# How do I call class method dynamically in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, oop

```
class Morning {
  greet() {
    return "Good Morning";
  }

  sayAnythingElse() {
    return "How are you doing in morning?"
  }
}

class Evening {
  greet() {
    return "Good Evening";
  }

  sayAnythingElse() {
    return "How are you doing in evening?"
  }
}
let time = '';
let method = '';
let rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
if (rndInt === 1) {
  time = 'Morning';
} else if (rndInt === 2) {
  time = 'Evening';
}

rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
if (rndInt === 1) {
  method = 'greet';
} else if (rndInt === 2) {
  method = 'sayAnythingElse';
}

// Please help to get rid of this if-else block
if (time === "Morning" && method === "greet") {
  let obj = new Morning();
  console.log(obj.greet());
} else if (time === "Morning" && method === "sayAnythingElse") {
  let obj = new Morning();
  console.log(obj.sayAnythingElse());
} else if (time === "Evening" && method === "greet") {
  let obj = new Evening();
  console.log(obj.greet());
} else {
  let obj = new Evening();
  console.log(obj.sayAnythingElse());
}
```

I want to invoke the class and its methods dynamically rather than defining if-else block.

Something like this => time.method

Here time and method both are dynamic. Object creation and invoking should happen depending upon its value. How can I achieve this in TypeScript.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: This should help you: https://www.cloudhadoop.com/2018/09/typescript-understanding-polymorphism.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as you are in TypeScript, you can create a `Time` interface as the base of your two classes. The `Time` interface can't be instanciated, only the classes can be.

This will declare the polymorphism, and you can use `keyof` to restrain the type of the `method` variable to only methods of your `Time` interface.

```
interface Time {
    greet(): string
    sayAnythingElse(): string
}

class Morning implements Time {
    greet() {
        return "Good Morning";
    }

    sayAnythingElse() {
        return "How are you doing in morning?"
    }
}

class Evening implements Time {
    greet() {
        return "Good Evening";
    }

    sayAnythingElse() {
        return "How are you doing in evening?"
    }
}

let time: Time; // Instance of Time, which is either Morning or Evening
let method: keyof Time; // A method of interface Time
let rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
if (rndInt === 1) {
    time = new Morning();
} else if (rndInt === 2) {
    time = new Evening();
}

rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
if (rndInt === 1) {
    method = 'greet'; // Here you have autocompletion of the method thanks to keyof
} else if (rndInt === 2) {
    method = 'sayAnythingElse';
}

// Your if is now removed
console.log(time[method]())
```